# Torah reading on shabbos and going out to finish davening

Tags: shabbat, torah-reading, tzibur-community

There have been times on Shabbos that I have been still davening when the *tzibbur* starts *Krias Hatorah*. Is it *halachically* correct to go outside of the place where they're reading to a more quiet place in the synagogue and finish up ?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Consider registering your account to unlock more features. Consider also taking the following short tour of the site: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: If you go outside, when will you hear Krias HaTorah?

Comment: What davenning are you proposing to go out and finish please?

Comment: @DannySchoemann , I guess you can add that to my question and @a

Comment: And @AvrohomYitzchok I apologize ; Shacharis davening.

Comment: @Selef1110 Yes: but which part? brochos, pesukei dezimra, krias shema and brochos or amidah?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues here:

**1. Walking out**

We learn in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch  [סימן כג - קצת דיני קריאת ספר תורה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0022_L2) that one may not walk out during Krias HaTorah. For a great need one may leave when the Torah is not being actually read.

> **סעיף ח':** 
>   כֵּיוָן שֶׁהִתְחִיל הַקּוֹרֵא לִקְרֹת, אָסוּר לְכָל הַקָּהָל לְדַבֵּר, אֲפִלּוּ בְּדִבְרֵי תּוֹרָה, וַאֲפִלּוּ בֵּין גַּבְרָא לְגַבְרָא, **וְאָסוּר לָצֵאת מִבֵּית הַכְּנֶסֶת בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁקּוֹרִין בַּתּוֹרָה**, אֲבָל בֵּין גַּבְרָא לְגַבְרָא שֶׁסֵּפֶר הַתּוֹרָה מְגֻלָל, יָכוֹל לָצֵאת לְצֹרֶךְ גָּדוֹל.‏

So if you feel you prefer to Daven rather than hear Krias HaTorah, then make sure to leave before they start reading, or between Aliyos, but not during the actual leining.

The Shulchan Aruch in [סימן קמו - שלא לדבר בשעת הקריאה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_9.html#HtmpReportNum0010_L2) is more explicit and seems to say that you may not walk out whenever the Sefer Torah is open.

> **א:** **אָסוּר לָצֵאת וּלְהַנִּיחַ סֵפֶר תּוֹרָה כְּשֶׁהוּא פָּתוּחַ**, אֲבָל בֵּין גַּבְרָא  לְגַבְרָא, שַׁפִּיר דָּמֵי.‏

**2. Hearing Krias HaTorah**

Even though the Mitzva of Krias HaTorah is a communal obligation - an individual does not have to hear Krias HaTorah of he misses it - nevertheless, if he's in shul, it seems that he should hear the reading.

All I could find is in the קיצור ש''ע ילקוט יוסף in [סימן קלה - סדר העולים לספר תורה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_part_8.html#HtmpReportNum0002_L2) where he says:

> **טו:** העומד בפסוקי דזמרה והצבור הגיעו לקריאת ספר תורה, אם הוא עתיד לשמוע קריאת ספר תורה ממנין אחר, אינו צריך להפסיק בפסוקי דזמרה כדי לשמוע קריאת התורה, אלא יפסיק לענות ''ברוך ה' המבורך לעולם ועד'', וכן לאמנים של ברכות התורה. אבל אם אינו עתיד לשמוע קריאת התורה ממנין אחר, יפסיק בין מזמור למזמור וישמע הקריאה עם הצבור.‏

Essentially, one may continue davening during Krias HaTorah if one will hear it in another Minyan. However, if one is not going to hear it in another Minyan, then one should interrupt one's davening to listen to Krias HaTorah.